# Making an adjustQuantity method stop at 0

Tags: java

I'm working on a project for my intro to Java class and we have to format a UML that is

```
+adjustQuantity(adjustingQuantity:int):void // Adjusts the book stored quantity by the given amount. The final
                                                                                       //    must be >= 0
```

I've got the code for adding the adjusted interval already applied,

```
public void adjustQuantity(int adjustingQuantity)
    { 
        int iAdjustingQuantity;
        int iQuantity= this.quantity;
        int iNewQuantity = (this.quantity + iAdjustingQuantity);
        if(iNewQuantity <=0)

    }
```

the problem I'm having is getting the value to stop at 0. I would just do an if statement that says "Return 0 if less than 0" but it's not returning anything so I can't do that... So my question is how do I get it to stay positive and not go negative?

Comment: typically you would want to know if your adjustment fails to take place.  since your return value is null, an exception would be used.

Comment: reduce the number of variables or correct your usage of iAdjustingQuantity (iAdjustingQuantity was not initialized).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
public void adjustQuantity(int adjustingQuantity) { 
    int iNewQuantity = this.quantity + adjustingQuantity;
    if (iNewQuantity >= 0)
        this.quantity = iNewQuantity 
    else
        this.quantity = 0;
}
```

With the above you guarantee that the quantity gets adjusted only if the new quantity is zero or positive, otherwise we assign zero.

Comment: That works great. Thank you! (I would give you a thumbs-up, but I don't have enough rep to do so, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the variable another time:

```
public void adjustQuantity(int adjustingQuantity)
    { 
        int iAdjustingQuantity;
        int iQuantity= this.quantity;
        int iNewQuantity = (this.quantity + iAdjustingQuantity);
        if(iNewQuantity <=0)
            iNewQuantity = 0;

        this.quantity=iNewQuantity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((adjustingQuantity+this.quantity) < 0)
  throw new Exception("adjustingQuantity must be greater than or equal to zero");
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic operation should be:

```
this.iQuantity = Math.max(iQuantity + iAdjustingQuantity, 0);
```

However, there is no reason to use the `i` prefix on your integer variables; your methods should be short enough that you don't need the prefix.  Besides, suppose your requirements change and and you must switch to `long`s.  Do you just change the type and have:

```
long iQuantity;
```

Now, what do you want to happen if the new value is negative?  Do you want to set it to zero? Do you want to throw an exception? Do you want to revert? This takes your decision.

@jcalfee314 suggested throwing an `Exception`; I would suggest a specific subclass of `Exception` instead.  `IndexOutOfBoundsException` does not seem quite right; I'd use `IllegalArgumentException`.

Probably the best way to use this in a large program is to use `PropertyChangeEvent`, `PropertyChangeListener` and `VetoableChangeListener`. Look up the JavaBeans specification, Section 7.4. Make `iQuantity` *bound* and *constrained*.